# remove item from a list within list in dict in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to delete value form y.value if value in x.

```
x = [[1,2],[2,6],[1,5],[5,6],[5,6],
    [10,11], [11,12], [3,4],[4,8],[8,7],[3,7]]

y = {'first':[[1,2],[2,6],[1,5],[5,6]],
    'second':[[2,3], [3,7],[7,6],[2,6]]}

for k,v in y.items():
    for a in v:
       if a in x:
          del a
```

output is

```
{'first': [[1, 2], [2, 6], [1, 5], [5, 6]], 
 'second': [[2,3], [3, 7], [7, 6], [2, 6]]}
```

need to be:

```
{'first': [], 
 'second': [[2, 3], [7, 6], [2, 6]]}
```

Comment: What do you think `del a` does?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I suppose del is delete a in list within a dict

Comment: have you considered using `remove` ? `del` is not the one that shld be used here. It is used to delete the variable and free the memory.

Comment: No, it deletes the *local variable `a`*, and decrements the reference counter.

Comment: Shouldn't your output be: `{'first': [], 'second': [[2, 3], [7, 6]]}` ?

Comment: @Bharathshetty when I try to use a.remove nothing happens

Comment: It's a shame those inner lists aren't 2 item tuples instead. You could make this code quite efficient if they were.

Comment: @Bharathshetty Beware of calling `remove` on a list you're iterating over, unless you iterate over it in reverse.

Comment: For example, see what this does: `a = list(range(8))` `for u in a:` `if u<8:` `a.remove(u)` `print(a)`

Comment: any answers given below are not given according to question expected output yet they are upvoted, shame

Comment: @shashi Please note that the expected output given in the question is incorrect: `[2,6]` is in `x` so it should _not_ be in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `remove`:

```
x = [[1,2],[2,6],[1,5],[5,6],[5,6],
    [10,11], [11,12], [3,4],[4,8],[8,7],[3,7]]

y = {'first':[[1,2],[2,6],[1,5],[5,6]],
    'second':[[2,3], [3,7],[7,6],[2,6]]}

for v in y.values():
    for _x in x:
        if _x in v:
            v.remove(_x)

print(y) # {'first': [], 'second': [[2, 3], [7, 6]]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a `set` of `tuple`s of your items that aren't wanted, then inplace update your dictionary and check that its innerlist item converted to a tuple isn't also in your list, eg:

```
unwanted = {tuple(el) for el in x}
y.update((k, [el for el in v if tuple(el) not in unwanted]) for k, v in y.items())
```

That leaves you with a `y` of:

```
{'first': [], 'second': [[2, 3], [7, 6]]}
```

Comment: Sir since you are using set is it ohk to use difference like `n ={ k:list(set({tuple(i) for i in y[k]}).difference(unwanted)) for k,v in y.items()}`

Comment: @Bharath If the order of the innerlists and duplicates are to be preserved then that woudn't be suitable here.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = [[1,2],[2,6],[1,5],[5,6],[5,6],
    [10,11], [11,12], [3,4],[4,8],[8,7],[3,7]]
>>> y = {'first':[[1,2],[2,6],[1,5],[5,6]],
    'second':[[2,3], [3,7],[7,6],[2,6]]}

>>> for k,v in y.items():
        y[k] = [a for a in v if a not in x]


>>> y
{'second': [[2, 3], [7, 6]], 'first': []}
```